# How to hide web-page scrolls preserving scrolling functionality

Tags: javascript, winapi, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scrollbar

I have a specific task, which requires to hide web-page scrollbars in Chrome, but preserve scrolling functionality (with keys and mousewheel). Currently I use

`document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';`

but this effectively disables scrolling.

Does anyone can suggest another way to fulfil the task via javascript or WinAPIs?

The code is actually placed inside a Chrome extensions (content script), so many things impossible for ordinary pages can be involved. Also I have a plugin which does already subclass Chrome window (Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND) for other purposes, so even more complicated methods are also welcomed.

According to MS Spy the Chrome window contains `WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR` style even when the scripted `style.overflow` is set to `hidden`. This makes me think, that the restriction is applied by the browser internally, and can not be removed by WinAPI calls.

EDIT:
I overlooked that WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR = 0x00000000, so it is implied by default and can not be eliminated.

EDIT2:
I came across `::-webkit-scrollbar` CCS styles, and it allows me for changing scrollbars width to 0! The scrollbar is *not visible* (just to distinguish this state to *hidden*) and works. Now the question is how can I change this style from javascript notation?

Comment: Do you want it to work on all of the major browsers or just on Chrome?

Comment: This is for Chrome only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the css way...
I tried inserting some css on an allready loaded page and the scrollbars never changed?

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id,{code:"::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important}"});
```

...even tried attaching it to the head and that didnt work either....

```
insertNoScrollBars=function (){
 if(document.getElementById('HideScrollBars') == null){
      var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
      var cssNode = document.createElement('style');
      cssNode.setAttribute('id','HideScrollBars');
      cssNode.innerText="::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important}"
      headID.appendChild(cssNode);
   }
}

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:"("+insertNoScrollBars+")()"});
    //chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id,{code:"::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important}"});
   }
);
```

Looking around it seems the scrollbars wont get updated unless theres some kind of refresh?....
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/117089

One thing that did work tho (altho it might not suit your needs) was to inject the css using content script settings in the manifest....
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Hide scrollbars",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "As the name says",
  "permissions": [
    "bookmarks", "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "run_at" : "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

**mystyles.css**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important}
```

**Or**
If the only reason you want to inject it programmaticly is so you only inject it if your settings say to then you could inject it with a content script at document start.....
**manifest.json**

```
 {
  "name": "Hide scrollbars",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "As the name says",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
// Do a check here to see if your settings say to hide the scrollbars or not
 if(document.getElementById('HideScrollBars') == null){
      var headID = document.documentElement;         
      var cssNode = document.createElement('style');
      cssNode.setAttribute('id','HideScrollBars');
      cssNode.innerText="::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important}"
      headID.appendChild(cssNode);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extended answer. I wanted to write a kind of it, but not so detailed.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle is apparently having some issues, but this is a good start for you. I used jQuery here as it cuts a lot of corners, but this can be translated into pure javascript. I believe you will need to bind to both `html` and `body` because of some browser quirks. I don't feel like doing the work for you, but if you need guidance let me know. Or if others want to take the time to write it they can feel free to co-opt my code.

```
//simulate mouse wheels. We us DOMMouseScroll for FF and mousewheel for all others
$('body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;

    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }
    else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + scrollTo);
    }
});

//monitor keypresses (you may want to use keypress or keydown instead). 
//remember that spacebar/shift-spacebar can also scroll screen full length.
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var scrollTo = 120;

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        console.log('down');            
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        console.log('up');
        scrollTo *= -1;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        console.log('spacebar');
        scrollTo = $(window).height();
    }

    $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop() + scrollTo);
});
```

Comment: What is supposed I should see on the page? The keys are pressed and logged, as they did in my tests either, but no scrolling. ;-(

Comment: @Stan - here, I added numbers so that you can see what's going on. You are in Chrome right? http://jsdo.it/tsherman/xrgI/fullscreen

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome. Now I see it woks on your page, but I can't get it working on mine. So the next question is should I apply different styles to my page? As you know I use `overflow` `hidden` here so far.

Comment: @Stan - I can't say why it doesn't work for you without your code. I also use overflow hidden in that example. Try adding some console.logs to the code and see if you get any output. Try manually calling `$('body').scrollTop(some num)` from console to see if settig it works. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/rbcJU/

Comment: As you presupposed in your answer, I changed your code to pure javascript and of course could make an error somethere. But the events are logged as well as in your page, and it scrolls if I remove `overflow` `hidden`. Your page is a little bit overloaded with other stuff so I can't say for sure which additions make it scroll. Inserted in a simple page with `overflow` `hidden`, it does not work for me. Anyway, thank you for the idea. I found another solution (CSS) which I like for a kind of grace, and use it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anyhing about chrome extension programming. If i had to do it on a webpage i'd try to use the jquery plugin jScrollPane http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ with some custom css.

Comment: I need to do it with entire web-pages, and the web-pages are not mine. This should work while a user browsers Web.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like <kbd>this</kbd>?

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/wZ5r2/

### What it does?

What it does is simply locked the scrollTop to a specific Y (or X if you want).

```
var scr = {
    ini: 0,
    locked: false,
    dis: function() {
        scr.ini = document.body.scrollTop;
        scr.locked = true;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if (scr.locked) {
                window.scrollTo(0, scr.ini);
            }
        })
    },
    en: function() {
        scr.locked = false;
    }
};​
```

### Advantage

- Very light;
- Very easy to understand too;
- 100% users will not able to scroll the page.

Hope it helps you out.